# Eclipse Compile Error: The type java.util.Collection cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type picocli.CommandLine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting an inexplicable error in my Eclipse IDE:

The type java.util.Collection cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type picocli.CommandLine

It is not allowing me to iterate a List object like the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import gov.uscourts.bnc.InputReader;
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;
...
List<ServerRecord> data = execute(hostnames);
    for (ServerRecord record : data) {
      hostInfoList.add(new String[] { record.hostname(), record.ip(), record.mac(), record.os(),
          record.release(), record.version(), record.cpu(), record.memory(), record.name(),
          record.vmware(), record.bios() });
    }
```

"data" is underlined in red and it says: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, checked Java version (21), updated Maven project, pom.xml specified target and source to be 21, deleted project and recreated it. Same error.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gov.uscourts.bnc.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>server-query</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>server-query</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                gov.uscourts.bnc.app.CollectServerData
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gov.uscourts.bnc</groupId>
            <artifactId>bnc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.picocli/picocli -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocli</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**I've just noticed ALL of my projects are doing this now. I have 8 I'm working on. I'm using picocli in all of them. I must have done something to Eclipse and broke something. Some of them were fully tested and running with no problems. **

Comment: Just to be sure - list is `java.util.List`, right? Not some custom class that just happens to have the same name?

Comment: Yes. I'll add my imports to the body.

Comment: Before you go any further, you need to stop using the variable name `record`. It's a reserved word. You don't by any chance have `java.awt.List` imported (maybe through wildcard)?

Comment: No. No awt at all. Weird that  Eclipse let me us record as a var. I changed it to "r" and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I suppose I could try using the old fashion Iterator and use .next() to iterate. No. I'll use IntelliJ or VSCode before I do that.

Comment: [`record` is a contextual keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-3.html#jls-ContextualKeyword), so you can use it as a variable name, but better avoid it for better readability. But this should not related to your issue. Please provide a [minimal and complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Check also whether in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ a Java 21 JDK is correctly configured. What happens if in the preferences _Java_ you hit the _Rebuild Index_ button?

Comment: I don't see a Rebuild Index anywhere. (I use the Mac version of Eclipse) I've been doing some other things in a different project and Eclipse thinks the Collection class is missing. This is in response to attempting to use the List addAll() method.

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE_)? Which Java 21 JDK do you have configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ (on macOS the preferences are in the application menu)?

Comment: Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) Build id: 20231201-2043. I'm using Oracle's jdk.

Comment: When I perform a Maven install it successfully compiles and creates my jar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed. It just went away. Do not know why it was occurring nor why it went away.